# how to indicate that there are no more items to return from server knockout js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am returning about 200+ items from the database and display but i would like to find out when there are no more items to return because i am using this in a scroll-load feature and would like to tell the user when they reached the end.

**Next - get next batch of users**

```
Next = function () {
    var _page = $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage() + 1;
    $.views.Roster.GetPage("/api/Roster", 9, _page);
};

$.views.Roster.GetPage = function (url, id, pageNumber) {
        $.grain.Ajax.Get({
            Url: url,
            DataToSubmit: { pageNumber: pageNumber, id: id },
            DataType: "json",
            OnSuccess: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.AddUsers(data);
                $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage(pageNumber);
            }
        });
    };
```

let me know if i am to provide anymore information.

Comment: Can you add a check...if(data.length == 0) showNoMoreMessage;, else do what you do?

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

If you are in control of the returned JSON **and** the format is modifiable (e.g. it's not some sort of publicly accessible web service), you could modify the returned response so that it contain the desired info as an additional field.

```
{
   users: [...your list of users data],
   hasMoreData: true
}
```

or...

assuming the data is returned in fixed-length batches, check the length of the returned batch, and if it's shorter than the expected length, consider it as a mark that there are no more item (this exposes you to a potential call with an empty result if the total records are an exact multiple of the batch length):

```
if (usersData.length < MAX_BATCH_LENGTH) {
   hasMoreData(false);
}
```